# c# source generator never called but crashes VS22

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a simple source generator. This is just a test because I never used source generators before. In the end, I want to read out generated internal classes defined in a certain file and edit them before adding them publicly to the source.

Test.Generators.csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>11</LangVersion>
    <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

TestGenerator.cs:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test.Generators
{
    [Generator(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
    public class TestGenerator: IIncrementalGenerator
    {

        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            var provider = context.SyntaxProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider(
                predicate: (c, _) => c is ClassDeclarationSyntax,
                transform: (n, _) => (ClassDeclarationSyntax)n.Node)
                .Where(m => m is not null);

            var compilation = context.CompilationProvider.Combine(provider.Collect());

            context.RegisterSourceOutput(compilation, (spc, source) => this.Execute(spc, source.Left, source.Right));
        }

        private void Execute(SourceProductionContext context, Compilation compilation, ImmutableArray<ClassDeclarationSyntax> typeList)
        {
            var code = """
                namespace Test.Generators.Generated;

                public static class GeneratorTests {
                    public const string Message = "Generator works"
                }
                """;

            context.AddSource("GeneratorTests.g.cs", code);
        }
    }
}
```

Test.Generators.Tests.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Test.Generators\Test.Generators.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyser"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs:

```
using Test.Generators.Generated;

namespace Test.Generators.Tests;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GeneratorTests.Message);

    }
}
```

The source generator is never called. No matter if I change files, build or rebuild any project or the whole solution. But there is one difference in the behavior that is caused. If I have the generator projects in my solution and restart VS22 it becomes unusable for about 2 minutes and afterwards, half of my configurations in the configuration manager are not selectable. Every Project has 5 configs. Debug, Release, TEST, PROD, and LOCAL. I can only select Debug and Release. This behavior never happened before and is solved when I delete the projects and restart VS22.